# iOS Tab Bar questions (Swift)

Tags: ios, uitabbar

I have a couple questions about the iOS tab bar.

My first question is, is the image always tinted automatically? Say for example, I used an image that was colored red, is there a way to get it to show the red without tinting it? I guess what I am saying is, can you show the natural color?

My second question is, assuming the tinting is mandatory, how would I go about tinting the images in the tab bar that are not the currently selected image? I have the selected image tint figured out.

I tried changing the tint under, UIView.appearance() I believe and that worked, but when I selected a different tab, and then navigated back the color went back to the former grayish color.

If I am not being clear enough, let me know and I will explain more. I am using swift, so any examples you give would be great in swift! Thanks!

Comment: "how would I go about tinting the images in the tab bar that are not the currently selected image" You can't. It used to be possible, but in iOS 7 Apple took this feature away! I regard this as a bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Say for example, I used an image that was colored red, is there a way to get it to show the red without tinting it?

What you want to do is to specify an [image with rendering mode](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiimage_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIImage/imageWithRenderingMode:) `.AlwaysOriginal`.

To govern both images, create the item with `initWithTitle:image:selectedImage:` and make them both `.AlwaysOriginal`.

(As you discovered, if you use a transparency mask and rely on the `tintColor`, you lose control of the tint color when unselected.)